# Rails, gmaps4rails - sidebar items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

Firstly, I just want to say that the gmaps4rails gem has been fantastic. Easy to setup and configure quickly.

My question relates to the sidebar that the gem generates. I've added a "def gmaps4rails_sidebar" method to my model and I want to define not just a hyperlink to the marker but also some other text that isn't wrapped in the  tag.

Is this possible? If not, what's the easiest way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing to customize the sidebar and I don't think I'll implement it because it's pretty easy for anyone to do it:

In the callback, loop the markers and get inspiration from [this really short function](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.base.js.coffee#L372).

Comment: Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community. If you're doing this then it usually means the questions are duplicates so flag them as such instead.

Comment: @Kev: the questions are close but no similar, but I definitely understand your point

Comment: Thanks for this response. You're right that it's easy to manipulate to get the desired result.